# Logbook clock entries as active/inactive time stamps in icalendar export

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs, time-date

Is there a way to automatically have active/inactive timestamps updated in the body of the org node? My final goal is to have the clock entries  included as events in icalendar export. Alternatively is it possible to make icalendar export  include logbook clocked entries?